# git ignore a file for changes but don't ignore the file for merge in the repository

Tags: git, merge, gitignore, checkout

I've updated .gitignore not to report changes to 200 files that are continuously regenerated from tracked source files during my development process. This cleans up my "git status" report just fine.

I use `git add -f .` in order to include the generated files in the push and, sure enough, I see my updated generated files on the server so that when my colleagues get a copy of the repository, the generated files are included. So far, so good.

But when I switch branches locally and merge the branch with the regenerated files, the regenerated files are ignored and I do not have them at hand to use them in the switched branch. I could regenerate them, but I want the merge to include all of the files in the repository so that the branch gets the complete image of the old branch. I would then use `git add -f .` on the new branch in order to update the server with the regenerated files from the old branch, but I don't have those regenerated files and I want them preserved because the regeneration process will add timestamps and such that won't match.

I tried an explicit git merge  which produces conflicts that end up embedded in all of the regenerated files, rendering the regenerated files useless. And I can't individually fix all 200 of them.

So how can I checkout a branch and have all of the current branch's files show up in the result without conflicts? Or how can I merge a branch and preserve the incoming .gitignore regenerated files without them getting peppered with conflict statements?

Comment: Being listed in `.gitignore` has no effect on tracked files, so I am not sure what your first paragraph is supposed to mean. (`git update-index` can be used to make `git status` ignore changes to tracked files.)

Comment: I updated .gitignore with the directories and names of all of the generated files and they disappeared from my `git status` which is what I wanted. But I still need the files to go up to the server, down from the server, and ignored in a merge (by ignored, I want the incoming files to overwrite existing). I had discounted `git update-index` based on the documentation that reads "Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually."

Comment: It is generally ill-advised to include generated files in a source code repository. This is the reason that Git does not support your workflow out of the box. I wouldn't be surprised if you can't get it to work at all.

Comment: Ah, I see: you must have run `git rm` (perhaps with `--cached`) to remove the files from the index (making them untracked) *and* listed them in `.gitignore`. If you made any commits in this state, those commits lack the generated files; once you `git add -f`, subsequent commits *do* have the generated files.

Comment: Thank you @j6t that helps. I'm moving to git from CVS where my execution environment (interpretive XSLT and generated intermediate files) is my source environment and I've simply cherry-picked those files that are tracked in CVS. I was led to believe I could do the same with git. So what is the typical practice with git? Executables are built in another directory as a separate step after obtaining a particular snapshot? If the build process is elaborate, it would take quite a while to get to the point where one can compare one commit from a different commit.

Comment: Yes, @torek, those are the steps I learned in order to keep the intermediate generated files in the same directory as the source files so that a checkout would (in theory) contain everything needed for execution.

Comment: @G.KenHolman what do you mean by `it would take quite a while to get to the point where one can compare one commit from a different commit.`?

Comment: @LinFelix, I am an impatient man. It takes minutes to build all of the runtime and then the runtime results from the source files before I can compare the results from one commit to those of a previous commit. When my runtime environment was in the git repository, I could just use `git checkout` and I could say "go" without having to rebuild the runtime environment. From what I've learned today, I am resigned now to having to rebuild my runtime environment every time I do a checkout from a different branch just to be able to compare results from another branch.

Comment: I see, often people would just want to compare their code with something like `git diff`. In your case committing/checking in the binaries and results of running the code seems feasible.
Are you not overwriting your results anyways when you rerun your code (with the same or a different version)?

Comment: Not quite. Once I rebuild the runtime environment, it is read-only and acts on files found in other directories. I'm going to explore a simple approach of committing/checking in the results but filtering the git reports to prevent the clutter.

Comment: What git reports?

Comment: The list of modified files. When I've run my build, over 200 files are changed. Doing a `git status` is meaningless unless I filter out the files I don't care about. Then the report is something I can work with.